# ActionScript E4X Get Tag Attributes

Tags: xml, actionscript-3, e4x

I am a real newbie when it comes to E4X, so please bear with me. I am working on an ActionScript 3.0 project which I would like to extract all of the attributes from an XML tag.

I have used the `XML.attributes()` method, but that only returns the **value** of each attribute/ I would like the to get all of the attribute names **and** attribute values for a given XML tag.

Could someone please show me as to how I could obtain this?

Thank you for your time,
spryno724

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Google is your friend](http://www.google.com/search?source=ig&hl=en&rlz=&=&q=adobe%20xml%20attributes&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&oq=#sclient=psy&hl=en&source=hp&q=adobe%20reference%20xml%20attributes&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&oq=&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.&fp=d1b78fcc53d84841)

```
var xml:XML = <example id='123' color='blue'/>
var attNamesList:XMLList = xml.@*;

trace (attNamesList is XMLList); // true
trace (attNamesList.length()); // 2

for (var i:int = 0; i < attNamesList.length(); i++)
{ 
    trace (typeof (attNamesList[i])); // xml
    trace (attNamesList[i].nodeKind()); // attribute
    trace (attNamesList[i].name()); // id and color
}
```

Comment: thanks I saw this too, but I'm having a hard time implementing this. not sure why yet. lol

Comment: well post a sample xml and tell me what node attributes you want

Comment: thanks for your pointers and willingness to help, but I finally got it!

Comment: Everytime I use Google, I end up in an answer that says "Why don't you use Google?". But thank God at least you answered.

Comment: @Veehmot an answer isn't an answer without an answer, so i included an answer. Pasting links don't qualify as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

`XML.attributes()` doesn't only return the value, you're just seeing the string serialization of the attributes. Given `attr = <foo bar="baz"/>.attributes()[0]`, `attr.localname() === "bar"` and `attr.toString() === "baz"`.